# How do you add arrowheads to lines drawn using canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a function that draws linear plots on a coordinate grid, as illustrated in the following JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zje14n92/1/

The component of the code that draws the linear plots (as opposed to the axes) is below:

```
if (canvas1.getContext) {
canvas1.width  = x_axis * 2;
canvas1.height = y_axis * 2;
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

ctx1.font = "10px sans-serif";
ctx1.strokeText('   ', x_axis+50, 50);

ctx1.lineWidth = 1;

ctx1.beginPath();

ctx1.strokeStyle = 'black';

x = -x_max;
y = 4*x + 5; // FIRST THING TO CHANGE TO CHANGE EQUATION (MUST USE * FOR MULTIPLICATION)
ctx1.moveTo(offsetX(x), offsetY(y));

while (x < x_max) { // INCLUDE CODE FOR BROKEN LINE IN HERE
    x += 0.1;
    y = 4*x+5; // SECOND THING TO CHANGE TO CHANGE EQUATION (MUST USE * FOR MULTIPLICATION)
    ctx1.lineTo(offsetX(x), offsetY(y));
}
ctx1.stroke();

ctx1.closePath();
```

I want the linear plots (I already figured out the axes) to end in arrows, but I cannot figure out how to do so. I found the code below in the following JsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Sg7EZ/), but I cannot figure out how to incorporate this into my existing code...or if this is, indeed, how I'm supposed to do it.

```
var startRadians=Math.atan((this.y2-this.y1)/(this.x2-this.x1));
startRadians+=((this.x2>this.x1)?-90:90)*Math.PI/180;
        this.drawArrowhead(ctx,this.x1,this.y1,startRadians);
        // draw the ending arrowhead
        var endRadians=Math.atan((this.y2-this.y1)/(this.x2-this.x1));
        endRadians+=((this.x2>this.x1)?90:-90)*Math.PI/180;
        this.drawArrowhead(ctx,this.x2,this.y2,endRadians);

    }

    Line.prototype.drawArrowhead=function(ctx,x,y,radians){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(x,y);
        ctx.rotate(radians);
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(5,20);
        ctx.lineTo(-5,20);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
        ctx.fill();
}
```

Is there some sort of simple way to turn the endpoints of lines into arrowheads? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**You have to find any point(s) where your (infinite) plot line exits the canvas (a rectangle).**

It might exit the canvas at 0, 1 or 2 points. If the plot line exits the canvas rectangle at 0 or 1 points you don't need the arrowheads. If the plot line exits the canvas rectangle at 2 points then place arrowheads at both exit points using your arrowhead fiddle.

To test for exit points you can think of the canvas rectangle as 4 lines forming the rectangle. Then test for intersections between the plot line and each of the 4 rectangle-lines.

**This script returns any intersection of 2 lines:**

```
// Attribution: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/
// p0 & p1 are points on a first line
// p2 & p3 are points on a second line
// returns the intersection point (or null if the lines don't intersect)
function line2lineIntersection(p0,p1,p2,p3) {

    var unknownA = (p3.x-p2.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p3.y-p2.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
    var unknownB = (p1.x-p0.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p1.y-p0.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
    var denominator  = (p3.y-p2.y) * (p1.x-p0.x) - (p3.x-p2.x) * (p1.y-p0.y);        

    // Test if Coincident
    // If the denominator and numerator for the ua and ub are 0
    //    then the two lines are coincident.    
    if(unknownA==0 && unknownB==0 && denominator==0){return(null);}

    // Test if Parallel 
    // If the denominator for the equations for ua and ub is 0
    //     then the two lines are parallel. 
    if (denominator == 0) return null;

    // If the intersection of line segments is required 
    // then it is only necessary to test if ua and ub lie between 0 and 1.
    // Whichever one lies within that range then the corresponding
    // line segment contains the intersection point. 
    // If both lie within the range of 0 to 1 then 
    // the intersection point is within both line segments. 
    unknownA /= denominator;
    unknownB /= denominator;

    var isIntersecting=(unknownA>=0 && unknownA<=1 && unknownB>=0 && unknownB<=1)

    if(!isIntersecting){return(null);}

    return({
        x: p0.x + unknownA * (p1.x-p0.x),
        y: p0.y + unknownA * (p1.y-p0.y)
    });
}
```

**Find any intersections of the plot line and the 4 canvas rectangle lines:**

```
var exitTop=line2lineIntersection(
    {x:0,y:0}, { x:canvas.width, y:0},
    yourLinePoint0, yourLinePoint1
);

var exitRight=line2lineIntersection(
    {x:canvas.width,y:0}, { x:canvas.width, y:canvas.height},
    yourLinePoint0, yourLinePoint1
);

var exitBottom=line2lineIntersection(
    {x:0,y:canvas.height}, { x:canvas.width, y:canvas.height},
    yourLinePoint0, yourLinePoint1
);

var exitLeft=line2lineIntersection(
    {x:0,y:0}, { x:0, y:canvas.height},
    yourLinePoint0, yourLinePoint1
);

var intersections=[];
if(exitTop){ intersections.push(exitTop); }
if(exitRight){ intersections.push(exitRight); }
if(exitBottom){ intersections.push(exitBottom); }
if(exitLeft){ intersections.push(exitLeft); }

if(intersections.length==2){
    // feed your 2 exit points into your arrow drawing script 
}
```

**Then feed your 2 exit points into your arrow drawing script:**

```
// create a new line object
var line=new Line(
    intersections[0].x, intersections[0].y,
    intersections[1].x, intersections[1].y
);

// draw the line
line.drawWithArrowheads(context);
```

**Example code and a Demo**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

function Line(x1,y1,x2,y2){
  this.x1=x1;
  this.y1=y1;
  this.x2=x2;
  this.y2=y2;
}
Line.prototype.drawWithArrowheads=function(){

  // arbitrary styling
  ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
  ctx.fillStyle="blue";
  ctx.lineWidth=1;

  // draw the line
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(this.x1,this.y1);
  ctx.lineTo(this.x2,this.y2);
  ctx.stroke();

  // draw the starting arrowhead
  var startRadians=Math.atan((this.y2-this.y1)/(this.x2-this.x1));
  startRadians+=((this.x2>this.x1)?-90:90)*Math.PI/180;
  this.drawArrowhead(ctx,this.x1,this.y1,startRadians);
  // draw the ending arrowhead
  var endRadians=Math.atan((this.y2-this.y1)/(this.x2-this.x1));
  endRadians+=((this.x2>this.x1)?90:-90)*Math.PI/180;
  this.drawArrowhead(ctx,this.x2,this.y2,endRadians);

}
Line.prototype.drawArrowhead=function(ctx,x,y,radians){
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(x,y);
  ctx.rotate(radians);
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(5,20);
  ctx.lineTo(-5,20);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.fill();
}

////////////////////////////////////

var x0=22.375;
var y0=678.625;
var x1=330.8125;
var y1=-555.125;

var exitTop=line2lineIntersection(
  {x:0,y:0}, { x:canvas.width, y:0},
  {x:x0,y:y0},{x:x1,y:y1}
);

var exitRight=line2lineIntersection(
  {x:canvas.width,y:0}, { x:canvas.width, y:canvas.height},
  {x:x0,y:y0},{x:x1,y:y1}
);

var exitBottom=line2lineIntersection(
  {x:0,y:canvas.height}, { x:canvas.width, y:canvas.height},
  {x:x0,y:y0},{x:x1,y:y1}
);

var exitLeft=line2lineIntersection(
  {x:0,y:0}, { x:0, y:canvas.height},
  {x:x0,y:y0},{x:x1,y:y1}
);

var intersections=[];
if(exitTop){ intersections.push(exitTop); }
if(exitRight){ intersections.push(exitRight); }
if(exitBottom){ intersections.push(exitBottom); }
if(exitLeft){ intersections.push(exitLeft); }

if(intersections.length==2){
  // feed your 2 exit points into your arrow drawing script
  for(var i=0;i<intersections.length;i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(intersections[i].x,intersections[i].y,3,0,Math.PI*2);
    //ctx.fill();
  } 
}


// create a new line object
var line=new Line(
  intersections[0].x, intersections[0].y,
  intersections[1].x, intersections[1].y
);

// draw the line
line.drawWithArrowheads();



// Attribution: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/
function line2lineIntersection(p0,p1,p2,p3) {

  var unknownA = (p3.x-p2.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p3.y-p2.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
  var unknownB = (p1.x-p0.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p1.y-p0.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
  var denominator  = (p3.y-p2.y) * (p1.x-p0.x) - (p3.x-p2.x) * (p1.y-p0.y);        

  // Test if Coincident
  // If the denominator and numerator for the ua and ub are 0
  //    then the two lines are coincident.    
  if(unknownA==0 && unknownB==0 && denominator==0){return(null);}

  // Test if Parallel 
  // If the denominator for the equations for ua and ub is 0
  //     then the two lines are parallel. 
  if (denominator == 0) return null;

  // If the intersection of line segments is required 
  // then it is only necessary to test if ua and ub lie between 0 and 1.
  // Whichever one lies within that range then the corresponding
  // line segment contains the intersection point. 
  // If both lie within the range of 0 to 1 then 
  // the intersection point is within both line segments. 
  unknownA /= denominator;
  unknownB /= denominator;

  var isIntersecting=(unknownA>=0 && unknownA<=1 && unknownB>=0 && unknownB<=1)

  if(!isIntersecting){return(null);}

  return({
    x: p0.x + unknownA * (p1.x-p0.x),
    y: p0.y + unknownA * (p1.y-p0.y)
  });
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**[Addition: add answer code into questioner's code]**

[image]

```js
/////////////
//
function Line(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    this.x1=x1;
    this.y1=y1;
    this.x2=x2;
    this.y2=y2;
}
Line.prototype.drawWithArrowheads=function(color){
    // arbitrary styling
    ctx.strokeStyle=color || "black";
    ctx.fillStyle=color || "black";
    ctx.lineWidth=1;   
    // draw the line
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.x1,this.y1);
    ctx.lineTo(this.x2,this.y2);
    ctx.stroke();
    // draw the starting arrowhead
    var startRadians=Math.atan((this.y2-this.y1)/(this.x2-this.x1));
    startRadians+=((this.x2>this.x1)?-90:90)*Math.PI/180;
    this.drawArrowhead(ctx,this.x1,this.y1,startRadians);
    // draw the ending arrowhead
    var endRadians=Math.atan((this.y2-this.y1)/(this.x2-this.x1));
    endRadians+=((this.x2>this.x1)?90:-90)*Math.PI/180;
    this.drawArrowhead(ctx,this.x2,this.y2,endRadians);
}
//
Line.prototype.drawArrowhead=function(ctx,x,y,radians){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(x,y);
    ctx.rotate(radians);
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(5,20);
    ctx.lineTo(-5,20);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.fill();
}
/////////////

var x_axis = 175;
var y_axis = 175;

var x_max = 7;  // THIS CHANGES RANGE OF X-AXIS
var y_max = 7; // THIS CHANGES RANGE OF Y-AXIS

var x_scale = x_axis / (x_max + 1);
var y_scale = y_axis / (y_max + 1);

var x_offset = x_axis + 0.5; // location on canvas
var y_offset = y_axis + 0.5; // of graph's origin


var canvas1 = document.getElementById("plot");
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

var canvas = document.getElementById("axes");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = canvas1.width  = x_axis * 2;
canvas.height = canvas1.height = y_axis * 2;

drawAxes(ctx);

plotline(-x_max,function(x){return(4*x+5);},'purple');
plotline(-x_max,function(x){return(3*x-1);},'blue');


function drawAxes(ctx) {
    ctx.font = "20px";
    
    ctx.font = "14px";
    ctx.strokeText('Y', x_axis - 25, 10);   //CHANGES LABEL OF Y-AXIS
    ctx.strokeText('X', x_axis * 2 - 10, y_axis + 20); //CHANGES LABEL OF X-AXIS

    ctx.font = "10px sans-serif";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;

    // draw x-axis
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, y_offset);
    ctx.lineTo(x_axis*2, y_offset);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    // draw arrow
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(10 - 8, y_axis+0.5);
    ctx.lineTo(10, y_axis+0.5 - 3);
    ctx.lineTo(10, y_axis+0.5 + 3);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x_axis*2+0.5, y_axis+0.5);
    ctx.lineTo(x_axis*2+0.5 - 8, y_axis+0.5 - 3);
    ctx.lineTo(x_axis*2+0.5 - 8, y_axis+0.5 + 3);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    // draw x values
    j = -x_max;
    while (j <= x_max) {
      x = j * x_scale;
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#aaa';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x + x_offset, y_offset);
      ctx.lineTo(x + x_offset, y_offset + 10);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();

      ctx.strokeStyle = '#666';
      ctx.strokeText(j, x + x_offset - 10, y_offset + 20);
    
      j++;
      if (j == 0) { j++; }
    }

    // draw y-axis
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x_offset, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x_offset, y_axis*2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    // draw arrow
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x_axis+0.5, 0.5);
    ctx.lineTo(x_axis+0.5 - 3, 0.5 + 8);
    ctx.lineTo(x_axis+0.5 + 3, 0.5 + 8);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x_axis+0.5, y_axis*2);
    ctx.lineTo(x_axis+0.5 - 3, y_axis*2 -8);
    ctx.lineTo(x_axis+0.5 + 3, y_axis*2 - 8);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    // draw y values
    j = -y_max;
    while (j <= y_max) {
      y = j * y_scale;
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#aaa';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x_offset, y + y_offset);
      ctx.lineTo(x_offset - 10, y + y_offset);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();

      ctx.strokeStyle = '#666';
      ctx.strokeText(-j, x_offset - 25, y + y_offset + 5);

      j++;
      if (j == 0) { j++; }
    }
}

function offsetX(v) {
 return x_offset + (v * x_scale);
}

function offsetY(v) {
 return y_offset - (v * y_scale);
}

/////////////////////////

function plotline(x,yFn,strokecolor){
    ctx1.font = "10px sans-serif";
    ctx1.strokeText('   ', x_axis+50, 50);
    ctx1.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx1.strokeStyle=strokecolor;
    
    drawLineWithArrowheads(
        offsetX(x),
        offsetY(yFn(x)),
        offsetX(x_max),
        offsetY(yFn(x_max)),
        strokecolor
    );
}
//
function drawLineWithArrowheads(x0,y0,x1,y1,color){
    var exitTop=line2lineIntersection(
        {x:0,y:0}, { x:canvas.width, y:0},
        {x:x0,y:y0},{x:x1,y:y1}
    );
    var exitRight=line2lineIntersection(
        {x:canvas.width,y:0}, { x:canvas.width, y:canvas.height},
        {x:x0,y:y0},{x:x1,y:y1}
    );
    var exitBottom=line2lineIntersection(
        {x:0,y:canvas.height}, { x:canvas.width, y:canvas.height},
        {x:x0,y:y0},{x:x1,y:y1}
    );
    var exitLeft=line2lineIntersection(
        {x:0,y:0}, { x:0, y:canvas.height},
        {x:x0,y:y0},{x:x1,y:y1}
    );
    //
    var intersections=[];
    if(exitTop){ intersections.push(exitTop); }
    if(exitRight){ intersections.push(exitRight); }
    if(exitBottom){ intersections.push(exitBottom); }
    if(exitLeft){ intersections.push(exitLeft); }
    //
    if(intersections.length==2){
        // create a new line object
        var line=new Line(
            intersections[0].x, intersections[0].y,
            intersections[1].x, intersections[1].y
        );
        // draw the line
        line.drawWithArrowheads(color);
    }
}


// Attribution: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/
function line2lineIntersection(p0,p1,p2,p3) {
    var unknownA = (p3.x-p2.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p3.y-p2.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
    var unknownB = (p1.x-p0.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p1.y-p0.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
    var denominator  = (p3.y-p2.y) * (p1.x-p0.x) - (p3.x-p2.x) * (p1.y-p0.y);        
    // Test if Coincident
    // If the denominator and numerator for the ua and ub are 0
    //    then the two lines are coincident.    
    if(unknownA==0 && unknownB==0 && denominator==0){return(null);}
    // Test if Parallel 
    // If the denominator for the equations for ua and ub is 0
    //     then the two lines are parallel. 
    if (denominator == 0) return null;
    // If the intersection of line segments is required 
    // then it is only necessary to test if ua and ub lie between 0 and 1.
    // Whichever one lies within that range then the corresponding
    // line segment contains the intersection point. 
    // If both lie within the range of 0 to 1 then 
    // the intersection point is within both line segments. 
    unknownA /= denominator;
    unknownB /= denominator;
    var isIntersecting=(unknownA>=0 && unknownA<=1 && unknownB>=0 && unknownB<=1)
    if(!isIntersecting){return(null);}
    return({
        x: p0.x + unknownA * (p1.x-p0.x),
        y: p0.y + unknownA * (p1.y-p0.y)
    });
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; }
canvas{left:0; position: absolute; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <canvas id="axes"></canvas>
  <canvas id="plot"></canvas>
```

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response. Thank you so much for this detailed write-up! I have tried incorporating this into my original code (https://jsfiddle.net/zje14n92/1/), but I am absolutely butchering it. I tried to at least generate an attempt at it, but I feel like it would be more confusing than helpful to my question. I'm particularly confused about how to incorporate the x1, x2, y1, y2 into my code. Would you be able to modify my JsFiddle to put an arrow on a line or at least help me figure out how to merge your write-up with my code? Complete novice - so much appreciated!

Comment: @user3666954. Sure. I have modified your original fiddle to show how the double-arrowhead code can be used. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Uh oh...in playing around with this, I just realized that I can no longer change the equations of the graphs to whatever I want. For example, it won't let me convert one of the linear plots to a parabolic plot by changing `plotline(-x_max,function(x){return(4*x+5);},'purple');` to `plotline(-x_max,function(x){return(x*x+5);},'purple');` Why did this ability disappear? Thanks!

Comment: Your question asks about plots of linear equations. If you ask a different question (about parabolic plots), the answer would, of course, differ. ;-)

Comment: Oohhhh. Darn, originally I had the JSfiddle working so that I could plot any equation (linear or non-linear). I was hoping to just add arrows to any equation I input. Even if the code isn't set up for it now, wouldn't the general premise that you suggested (looking for "exit points" that intersect with the exterior of the canvas) still work?

Comment: @user3666954. Sure. You just need to substitute an algorithm that finds the exit points of your parabola plot. It might be easier to test points along your equation and see when they exit the canvas empirically.

Comment: This is probably not allowed on this forum, but would you mind messaging me? I'd be willing to give you money to fix the issue so it works for all equations and not just linear equations.

Comment: @user3666954. I think SO allows for-profit meetings and I do contract work if the work is interesting. But before you pull out your paypal password I have a question: Will all your plots exit the canvas or will some plots terminate inside the canvas? If all plots exit the canvas I have a simple solution for you. (1) Plot the equation and examine all border pixels. (2) If any border pixel is opaque (opaque==on the plot) then just draw an outbound arrow at that position on the border. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The last 4 lines of that jsFiddle show the usage:

```
    // create a new line object
    var line=new Line(50,50,250,275);
    // draw the line
    line.drawWithArrowheads(context);
```

(but you'll also need the definition of `Line` from the top of the jsFiddle).

Anyway, what the code does is figure out the angle the line is heading and then just draws a triangle at that angle.

- It saves state, then
- it uses translate to move to the line end, then
- it uses rotate to orient the arrowhead, then
- it forms the arrowhead path, then
- it fills in the path, and finally
- it restores the state

by far the trickiest bit is finding the angle to orient the arrowhead.
Since you have a multi-point line, presumably you would just use that last two points for that.